# Erro ao gravar as informações de uma página ASP.NET no banco de dados

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em ASP.NET (VB.NET) com dois RadioButtonList e uma TextBox onde essas informações são retornadas pelo VB e gravadas no banco de dados, ao clicar em gravar o sistema apresenta o erro descrito abaixo e as informações não são inseridas no banco.

Contudo ao realizar o mesmo procedimento em modo de depuração o erro não ocorre.

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

**PesquisaAtendimento.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function abrirModal(id) {

        var alturaTela = $(document).height();
        var larguraTela = $(form1).width();

        var left = ($(window).width() / 2) - ($(id).width() / 2);
        var top = 100;

        $(id).css({ 'top': top, 'left': left });
        $(id).show();

    }

    $(document).ready(function ApresentaModal() {
        $("a[rel=modal]").click(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr("href");
            abrirModal(id);

        });
    });

    document.onload = abrirModal('#janela1');

    function close_window() {
        if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
            $('#I1').remove();
            close();
        }
    }

</script>
```

```
    <div class="janela" style="top: 100px; left: 178px; display: block;" id="janela1">
        <br />
        <div>

            <div style="float: left; width: 100%; height: 180px; border: none;">
                <div style="float: left; width: 100%;">
                    <span style="margin-left: 3px; font-size: 18px; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bolder; color: #0a78b7;">Por favor, atribua uma nota ao atendimento:</span>
                </div>
                <br />

                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblVotos" runat="server" Style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 0.8em; color: #043668;"
                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList><br />
                <div style="float: left; margin-left: 3px; width: 95%;">
                    <span style="margin-left: 3px; font-size: 0.8em; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;">Observações:</span>
                    <br />

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtObs" runat="server" Columns="65" Rows="2" TextMode="MultiLine"
                        Font-Names="Tahoma" Style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 0.8em; color: #043668; border: none;"
                        CssClass="txtObs" Width="590" Height="120"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <span style="margin-left: 3px; font-size: 0.8em; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bold; color: #0a78b7;">Todos os problemas foram resolvidos?</span>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblProblemasResolvidos" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 3px; font-size: 0.8em; font-family: Tahoma; color: #043668;"
                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="S">Sim</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="N">Não</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnGravar" runat="server" CssClass="btnGravar" Text="Gravar"
                        Height="32px" Width="71px" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblInformacao" runat="server" ForeColor="blue"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Conheço duas soluções para você:

1. Desabilitar o EventValidation, colocando o código `<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>`  no inicio do seu código (não recomendo, pois perde muito em segurança, mas dependendo do seu caso...)
2. Utilize o UpdatePanel, você ira encontrar mais informações:
   [aqui](https://imasters.com.br/framework/dotnet/trabalhando-com-updatepanel-no-asp-net/?trace=1519021197&source=single) e [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb386452(v=vs.100).aspx)